# Buck Converter Step Response Analysis

Tags: power-electronics, buck, control-system, pid-controller, simulink

I am new to power electronics and control, so I am confused with the following. I have a simulation of a Buck converter, and PID controller in Simulink. I did some trial and error tuning, and I have certain PID parameters. I am supposed to do a step response analysis. Does that mean that the input voltage block will become a step function? For example, if the input voltage is a DC source of 24V, the block should be changed to step function from 0 to 24V?
The problem is that I am not sure where to connect the step function block, and how to set it up (as a voltage source or as a PWM input).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: As pointed out in the [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/694886/101063) it is ambiguous what ``step response analysis`` means. Can the question to be edited to clarify what analysis needs to be performed. Also, adding a picture of the existing Simulink model may help to get a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

I can see you are trying to tune a PID filter for stabilizing a buck converter. My advice is to *not* tune the PID parameters directly but work with poles and zeroes for the compensation strategy. A PID, alone, is not adapted for loop control of noisy switching converters as it places a pole at the origin and two zeroes. As a result, you do not roll-off the gain at high frequency which is a problem for closed-loop systems.

Rather than a PID, you may want to consider a *filtered* PID version in which an additional pole is added for flattening the response in high frequency. Finally, if you add a third pole, you then have a classical type 3 compensator which is standard in power supply compensation. You will find details on these structures in my [APEC 2021](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202021.pdf) seminar.

When you stabilize a buck in voltage-mode control, you determine the resonant frequency \$f_0\$ which depends on the inductor and the output capacitor. The compensation strategy consists of placing a zero at \$f_0\$ and a second one, lower, to provide additional phase margin when the converter transitions in the discontinuous mode of operation (DCM). Then, you place one pole at half the switching frequency and a second one that you adjust to meet the phase margin target, like 70° for instance. You immediately realize that meeting these goals by adjusting \$k_d\$, \$k_p\$ and \$k_i\$ to obtain a crossover frequency with a given phase margin is an almost impossible exercise with trial and error.

I therefore recommend that you compute the PID coefficients from poles and zeroes you will choose based on the wanted performance. I have simulated a buck converter using SIMPLIS with a filtered PID featuring an extra pole and it is shown below:

[image]

I built a macro in which you enter the poles and zeroes you want, then the parameters are calculated to meet the design goals (a crossover of 10 kHz with a given phase margin) and finally, translated into PID parameters. Once you have them, you can pass them to your Simulink engine and see the results:

[image]

Then, you can check the compensated loop gain and make sure the transient response meets your goal. Here, the output current is stepped from 3 to 5 A, with a 1-A/µs slope:

[image]

You can find ready-made examples in my 100+ [free templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) which work, for most of them, on the free demo of SIMPLIS. The analog PID example is in the compensator [ZIP file](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Divers/Compensators%20SIMPLIS.zip) and includes analog and digital versions.

Answer (score 1):

A step response analysis could mean a step-change in the load or a step change in the input supply. Either way it won't mean a load step-change from open-circuit to full load nor a step-change from 0 volts to 24 volts.

If doing the input voltage step-change, it might mean changing the input supply voltage from 23.5 volts to 24.5 volts for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In Simulink, there is a block called "step" if I remember correctly. The step voltage can be specified in that block and the instance of step can also be specified. You can connect it to the input side of your converter. The input side will now be a "controlled voltage source" block.